# asp.net c# checking error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I want to check a selected date out of `txtFrom` and compare if that specific date exists. It should give me an alert, but it doesn't check. As a beginner I don't know if I wrote the code well, please can somebody help me? These are my codes:

```
string conn = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DIVIHOTELConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection myconn = new SqlConnection(conn);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from MyBooking where FromDate='" + txtFrom.Text + "'", myconn);
myconn.Open();
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
dr.Read();
if (txtFrom.Text == dr.GetString(1))
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "showalert","alert('This particular date has been booked already, please select new date !');", true);
}
```

Comment: any runtime error?

Comment: Learn how to use parameters. Concatenating strings (in particular with dates) is guaranteed to give wrong results at its best. And in worst case you could easily loose your whole database because you allow your user to type anything in that textbox (Sql Injection)

Comment: What is the data type of FromDate? Assuming datetime. You are doing a Select *, so what is the field order you are reading in your data reader? You should select the column names in case the schema changes.

Comment: And also if you are comparing with date then convert you date in C# from string to Date.

Comment: FromDate is varchar ,  shall i change to datetime and remove the*?

Comment: Just my two cents, but I would probably run a DateTime.TryParse() on the user input before anything else to assure they put in a valid date.

Comment: how do i do that?   like i said just beginner

Comment: What are column name and order of sequence in `Select *`

Comment: [ID]
      ,[ClientID]
      ,[RoomID]
      ,[Amount]
      ,[DateBooked]
      ,[IsInBook]
      ,[FromDate]
      ,[EndDate]

Comment: GetString(1) will give you value of second column, so are you sure you want to check second column?. also better to select the required column only not select *

Comment: try GetString(6) instead of GetString(1)

Comment: thank you very much it worked with the 6

Answer (score 2):

It is very clear that if your query returns column in this sequence `[ID] ,[ClientID] ,[RoomID] ,[Amount] ,[DateBooked] ,[IsInBook] ,[FromDate] ,[EndDate]`  and you accessing `dr.getString(1)` then this will return value for `[ClientID]` not for `[FromDate]`.

Try to use exact sequence number of column so that to get work done.

```
if (txtFrom.Text == dr.GetString(7))
{                          ------^
     //your code here
}
```

Comment: but now when i write a date that doesn't exist, it gives me error

Comment: An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.

Comment: Try to use `dr.GetString(6)`. I just given sample number `7` for sequence

Comment: it worked with the 6 for an existing date but  not a new date

Comment: Put another if statement on the outside of this one to first check if dr.GetString(6) != null

Answer (score 1):

My Suggestion

Check what you storing in db and what is your input date which you are comparing both are same or not, because your datatype is `varchar`

As per my understating you will get result when your time also match with date. likely i will say you will not get result with your current scenario.

Comment: but now when i write a date that doesn't exist, it gives me error

Comment: An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.

Answer (score 1):

First, filter query with proper date format i.e. Parameter be in data format 
Second, while reading data from datareader, specify the proper column name.